# Xcode won't build IB plugin into resources folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've created a custom control and a framework/IB plugin for it using the IB3 plugin template.

According to the docs the plugin should be built right into the resources directory of the framework.  When I build my project the plugin is in the configuration folder (Debug) along with the framework instead.

This is the same behavior right out of the box when I create a new template.  I tried changing the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` to be `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)/FrameworkName.framework/Resources/` but got no change.

For grins I also tried messing with the install path, but also got nowhere.  I've checked out a couple other open source projects to check their build settings, but they're identical to my own and yet their plugin is built and put into the resources directory as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with build settings. Instead, add a "Copy Files" build phase to the framework target. In the inspector for the copy files build phase, set the directory to "Resources". Add the plugin to this build phase by dragging the plugin product from the "Products" group in the "Groups & Files" tree in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Barry.  When I tried using a copy files build phase, IB wasn't able to resolve the connection between the framework and the plugin.  It couldn't find the associated plugin for some reason.

However, after endless fiddling, I found that I was closer than I thought.  Changing the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` to:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/FrameworkName.framework/Resources/
```

and updating the framework search paths solved the problem for me.  This isn't the behavior of the plugin template (at least on my machine) out of the box, so hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To get the built product of one Xcode target to be included in the resources directory of another Xcode target's product, you should find the product in the groups and files tree and drag the product into the copy "bundle resources phase" of the other target. You should also add a target dependency between the two targets with the get info panel for the target.

If you're seeing the built plug-in in the build products directory that does not mean that it wasn't also copied into the framework's resources directory. Xcode builds all targets into the build directory, and then copies (not moves) them into their final destination - which in this case is the framework's resources directory. One reason for this is that a product can have multiple final destinations.